# How to send form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded both in same POST request in ios?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, urlencode, form-data

I have a problem. I am making POST request to server. In which I am uploading an Image with user_id of User.I need to send user_id in x-www-form-urlencoded and Image in from-data. I tried many ways but every time user_id is undefined in server. How can I send both in same request.
Here is my **CODE:**

```
   NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MY URL TO UPLOAD IMAGE "]];
urlString=[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
           NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:100];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



NSString *boundary = @"------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";


NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

 NSDictionary *params = @{@"user_id":@"213"};
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

 for (NSString *param in params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: x-www-form-urlencoded; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}


// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .3);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"my-file\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",@"213"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}



[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLResponse *urlResponse;

NSError *error;

NSData * data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
```

**Output:** data = nil

Answer (score 0):

In order to send your data through `POST`

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"value1=test3&value2=test"];
[request setHTTPBody:[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```